# adding regression line in python using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, regression, interpolation, spyder, analysis

I have a question about drawing a regression line and determining the slope of that line. I am doing research for water heights of inland lakes in Tibet with the help of satellite date. I have the data for one year of one lake in this script.

However I want to determine the annual rise of the lake for as well the reference height as for the total beams. Is there some one that could help me?

[image]

This is the link towards the excel file: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/12wD2ByQC6ObNCWq_yIhkXiNsV3KfDpit/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTk1V.png)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Graph in chronological order
heights = pd.read_excel ('Qinghai_dates_heights.xlsx')
dates = (heights.loc[:,'Date'])
strong_beams = (heights.loc[:,'Strong total'])
weak_beams = (heights.loc[:,'Weak total'])
total_beams = (heights.loc[:,'Total'])

# setting the reference data from Hydrolabs
reference_dates = (heights.loc[:,'Date.1'])
reference_heights = (heights.loc[:,'Hydrolabs'])

# Set the locator
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
# Specify the format - %b gives us Jan, Feb...
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')


#plt.plot(dates,strong_beams, label='Strong Beams',  marker="o")
#plt.plot(dates,weak_beams, label='Weak Beams',  marker="o")
plt.plot(dates, total_beams, label='Total Beams',  marker="o")
plt.plot(reference_dates, reference_heights, label='Reference height (Hydrolabs)',  marker="o")



X = plt.gca().xaxis
X.set_major_locator(locator)
# Specify formatter
X.set_major_formatter(fmt)
plt.xlabel('Date [months]')
plt.ylabel('elevation [m]')
plt.title("Water-Height Qinghai from November 2018 - November 2019  ")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ? I usually use sklearn for this.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets
```

Generate a set of data

```
X = np.linspace(0, 10)
line_X = X[:, np.newaxis]
Y = X + 0.2*np.random.normal(size=50)
```

Choose your regression model (there are [plenty more](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#linear-model), depending on your needs)

```
lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
```

Here you really do the fit

```
lr.fit(line_X, Y)
```

Here u extract the parameters, since you seems to need it ;)

```
slope = lr.coef_[0]
intercept = lr.intercept_
```

And then you plot

```
plt.plot(X, slope*X + intercept, ls='-', marker=' ')
plt.plot(X, Y)
```

[image: plot of the data and the fit]

Comment: Thank your for the explaination, however the problem still holds.

I am using dates on the X-axis and there originates the problem. It does not interpolate due to the fact that it are dates